# Harmonizing dates

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a data frame with dates and the time in it.

Now I want to convert each date into the correct month. How can I do this?

Now it looks like this:

```
1   01.01.2019 00:00:20.747000
2   21.04.2019 00:00:21.362000
3   31.08.2019 00:00:21.422000
```

I need it in a format like this:

```
1   01.01.2019
2   21.04.2019 
3   31.08.2019
```

or eventually like this:

```
1 January
2 April
3 August
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R, you can do the following.

First, I wasn't sure if initial data frame was in `POSIXct` format. I converted it for my example.

Then you can use `format` to extract the month number or month name.

`lubridate` is a great package to use for various date manipulations as well and has `month` function.

```
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS")
df$date_only <- as.Date(df$datetime)
df$month_num <- format(df$datetime, "%m")
df$month <- format(df$datetime, "%B")
df
```

**Output**

```
             datetime  date_only month_num   month
1 2019-01-01 00:00:20 2019-01-01        01 January
2 2019-04-21 00:00:21 2019-04-21        04   April
3 2019-08-31 00:00:21 2019-08-31        08  August
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(datetime = c("01.01.2019 00:00:20.747000", "21.04.2019 00:00:21.362000", 
"31.08.2019 00:00:21.422000")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df$date <- lubridate::dmy_hms(df$date)

df$date <- format(df$date, "%d.%m.%Y")
```

data:

```
df: structure(list(date = c("01.01.2019", "21.04.2019", "31.08.2019"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```